# iOS 11 & Ionic 3 implement a BlueTooth connection with BluetoothSerial cordova plugin

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im trying to connect a neurosky MindWave (detects brain signals) with this plugin:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/bluetooth-serial/
provided by Ionic.
But when I try to discover available devices I'm getting this error:

> Method 'discoverUnpaired:' not defined in Plugin 'BluetoothSerial'

Here's my code:

```
this.bluetoothSerial.discoverUnpaired().then((success) => {
  success.forEach(device => {
      console.log('Device detected! - ' , device);
    });
  },
  (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```